# join on a calculated column value fails to give the expected result

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

table movimenti

| id | data | data_val | descrizione | banca | movimento | importo | id_volte | saldo_carta | utenza | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-03-14 | 2021-03-14 | Rata Mutuo | 6 | 21 | 560.00 | 5 | NULL | 2 | 2021-03-02 17:57:38 |
| 4 | 2021-04-14 | 2021-04-14 | Rata Mutuo | 6 | 21 | 560.00 | 5 | NULL | 2 | 2021-03-02 17:57:38 |
| 27 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 6 | 20 | 2500.00 | 6 | NULL | 2 | 2021-03-02 17:57:47 |
| 28 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 6 | 20 | 2500.00 | 6 | NULL | 2 | 2021-03-02 17:57:47 |
| 49 | 2021-03-02 | 2021-04-16 | prova | 6 | 21 | 134.00 | 0 | 3032021 | 2 | 2021-03-02 19:23:02 |
| 51 | 2021-03-05 | 2021-04-16 | prova1 | 6 | 21 | 432.00 | 0 | 3032021 | 2 | 2021-03-02 19:48:35 |

table movimenti_periodici

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Singolo |
| 5 | mutuo |
| 6 | stipendio |

Table causali

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | Interessi Attivi |
| 24 | Interessi Passivi |
| 21 | Rata Mutuo |
| 13 | Saldo carta di credito |
| 20 | Stipendio |

Query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(data_val) as data, 
    IF(COUNT(*) > 1, 'Saldo Carta', MAX(descrizione)) AS descrizione,
    IF(COUNT(*) > 1, 13, MAX(movimento)) AS movimento,
    MAX(causali.nome),
    SUM(importo) as importo, 
    MAX(movimenti_periodici.nome) as periodico
FROM `movimenti` 
    JOIN causali ON movimenti.movimento=causali.id 
    JOIN movimenti_periodici ON movimenti.id_volte=movimenti_periodici.id 
WHERE movimenti.utenza=2 
    AND data BETWEEN '2021-03-01'  AND '2021-04-30' 
    AND movimenti.banca=6
 group by saldo_carta, data_val
 ORDER BY data_val ASC
```

Expected result

| data | descrizione | movimento | nome | importo | periodico |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-14 | Rata Mutuo | 21 | Rata Mutuo | 560.00 | mutuo |
| 2021-03-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 20 | Stipendio | 2500.00 | stipendio |
| 2021-04-14 | Rata Mutuo | 21 | Rata Mutuo | 560.00 | mutuo |
| 2021-04-16 | Saldo Carta | 13 | Saldo Carta di credito | 566.00 | Singolo |
| 2021-04-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 20 | Stipendio | 2500.00 | stipendio |

My query works fine and aggregates together rows `49` and `51` of table `movimenti` (see expected results and actual results for `2021-04-16` row). For this aggregated movement `movimento` is correctly set to `13` but I cannot use `13` in the join with `causali` to show the nome matching `13`. It is currently returning the `MAX(nome)` from the rows that have been aggregated. The actual result looks like this:

Actual result

| data | descrizione | movimento | nome | importo | periodico |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-14 | Rata Mutuo | 21 | Rata Mutuo | 560.00 | mutuo |
| 2021-03-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 20 | Stipendio | 2500.00 | stipendio |
| 2021-04-14 | Rata Mutuo | 21 | Rata Mutuo | 560.00 | mutuo |
| 2021-04-16 | Saldo Carta | 13 | Rata Mutuo | 566.00 | Singolo |
| 2021-04-27 | Stipendio Mensile | 20 | Stipendio | 2500.00 | stipendio |

How can I get my expected result?

Comment: Please give DDL & initialization as code not a grid. PS Explain why you expect what you expect when you get unexpected results, justified by reference to authoritative documentation.  This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do it is to replace:

```
MAX(causali.nome)
```

with:

```
IF(COUNT(*) > 1, (SELECT nome FROM causali WHERE id = 13), MAX(causali.nome))
```

because as I see in your code, `13` is a hardcoded value.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb1b98c7455f7fc1fa35992c14249273) (where I also used aliases for all the tables to shorten the code and make it more readable).

Comment: That's a great approach. Thank you for suggesting it. For the aliases, I prefer to use plain names because I find it better to read (but that's just imho)

Comment: @LelioFaieta fine about the aliases, but at least you should qualify all the columns (even if there are not any duplicate column names) with the table's name. It's a good practice and saves you from problems that are hard to spot.

Comment: yes, you are right. That's something I need to start working on

Answer (score 1):

You need a computed ON condition for joining your `causali` table, to pick up the `nome` of the `moviemento` item.

A good way to handle this is to start with a subquery creating  just the summary you need.

```
  SELECT data_val,
         IF(COUNT(*) > 1, 'Saldo Carta', MAX(descrizione)) AS descrizione,
         IF(COUNT(*) > 1, 13, MAX(movimento)) AS movimento,
         SUM(importo) AS importo,
         MAX(id_volte) id_volte
    FROM `movimenti` 
   WHERE movimenti.utenza=2 
     AND data BETWEEN '2021-03-01'  AND '2021-04-30' 
     AND movimenti.banca=6
   GROUP BY data_val
```

Then use an outer query to look up the names associated with `id_volte` and `movimento`.

```sql
SELECT data_val, 
       descrizione,
       movimento,
       causali.nome,
       importo,
       movimenti_periodici.nome periodico
  FROM ( /* that subquery */ ) summary                             
  JOIN causali ON summary.movimento = causali.id 
  JOIN movimenti_periodici ON summary.id_volte=movimenti_periodici.id 
 ORDER BY data_val
```

That way you separate the work of summarizing your transactions from the work of annotating it with names, and get away from most of that `MAX(nome)` stuff.

Here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64JkvyM2bxQ4wRJorJq8t4/3